# Auto MsgBox when Excel file is opened and a condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

I suspect this is a pretty easy answer but I'm new to VBA and trying to generate a msgbox when I open my file and a certain condition is met. My code, as it currently stands, is:

```
Sub StopLossWarning()

    If Range("C4").Value < 30 Then

        MsgBox "Maximum allowable loss is at " & Range("C4").Value

    End If

End Sub
```

The Msgbox appears fine when I run the macro. I just need it to run once automatically when I open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Press Alt+F11 to open VBA Editor
2. Double click on ThisWorkbook from Project Explorer

   Copy the below code and paste there.

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim WK As Worksheet

   Set WK = Sheet1 'Change it to your sheet number.

   If WK.Range("C4").Value < 30 Then
     MsgBox "Maximum allowable loss is at " & WK.Range("C4").Value
   End If
   End Sub
   ```

Alternatively You can insert a new module and paste the code below there:

```
    Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim WK As Worksheet
    
    Set WK = Sheet1 'Change it to your sheet number.

    If WK.Range("C4").Value < 30 Then
      MsgBox "Maximum allowable loss is at " & WK.Range("C4").Value
    End If
    End Sub
```

Note: If you have multiple worksheet you may want to refer to ranges explicitly. Otherwise you may get undesired result

[Reference](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/run-macro-automatically-opening-workbook/)

Comment: Try the alternate code. Reasons why didn't work : 1. You are referring to wrong sheet. OR/AND  2.You pasted the code in the wrong place.

Comment: Looks like all I had to do was to change the the first line to: Sub Auto_Open(). I thought one could name their subs to whatever they wanted, didn't realize there are specific names for certain procedures. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep The other one is right as well but you need to select the right Sub from project Explorer before writing any code there.